# How can I find the maximum concurrent events per group given only start and end dates?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like something this:

```
site       event_start_date       event_end_date

A          2021-05-01             2021-08-06
A          2021-07-02             2022-02-21
B          2020-06-07             2021-02-03
B          2021-01-11             2022-01-23
C          2019-03-09             2021-02-05
...        ......                 .........
```

Basically, for each site, I have a list of events, each with a start date and end date. I would like to figure out, for each site, what is the maximum number of events actively occurring at that site on any given day. Do you know if there is a relatively simple way to do this in R? The only solution I could come up with is to create a sparse matrix (with 1 column for each day) indicating whether each event was active on each particular day, summing each column for each site, and then taking the maximum value. However, as the possible date range spans several years, this would potentially involve over 1000 columns (with several hundred thousand rows) and may not be the most efficient approach (or even feasible from a memory perspective). Any more streamlined solutions would be much appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd approach it is to convert the data to longer format, encode starts as +1 and ends as -1, and then take the cumulative sum by group. This should be pretty efficient and fast since it relies on a vectorized calculation on a single column, and only tracks the dates with changes.

If you have very large data, it might be worth using the `data.table` or `collapse` packages to speed up the aggregation steps. Both can be accessed using dplyr code as the front end, e.g. by using the `dtplyr` wrapper package or by [setting collapse's options to mask dplyr](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/reference/collapse-options.html).

You might also add a step to combine all the daily changes if you are only interested in the end-of-day value, e.g. by adding `count(site, value, wt = chg) %>%` after the `mutate(chg...` line.

---

```
library(tidyverse)

# load data
tibble::tribble(
  ~site, ~event_start_date, ~event_end_date,
    "A",      "2021-05-01",    "2021-08-06",
    "A",      "2021-07-02",    "2022-02-21",
    "B",      "2020-06-07",    "2021-02-03",
    "B",      "2021-01-11",    "2022-01-23",
    "C",      "2019-03-09",    "2021-02-05"
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("date"), as.Date)) %>%

  # reshape and encode start as +1, end as -1
  pivot_longer(-site) %>%
  mutate(chg = if_else(name %>% str_detect("start"), 1, -1)) %>%

  # take the cumulative sum by group
  arrange(site, value) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(active = cumsum(chg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # plot
  ggplot(aes(value, active, color = site, group = site)) +
  geom_step()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is brilliant Jon, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!